# how to reduce execution time

Tags: c++, algorithm, time

Currently the following problem is taking 3.008** seconds to execute for some testcase       provided on hackerearth.com   where allowed time is 3.0 seconds so i get time limit error.  Please help to reduce execution time.

Problem:
    Alice has just learnt multiplying two integers. He wants to multiply two integers X and        Y to form a number Z.To make the problem interesting he will choose X in the range [1,M]     and Y in the range [1,N].Help him to find the number of ways in which he can do this.

Input

First line of the input is the number of test cases T. It is followed by T lines. Each   line has three space separated integers, the numbers Z, M and N.

Output

For each test case output a single integer, the number of ways.

Constraints
    1 <= T <= 50 
    1 <= Z <= 10^12
    1 <= M <= 10^12
    1 <= N <= 10^12

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int chk_div(long long a,long long b)
{
if(((a/b) * (b) )==a)return 1;
return 0;
}

int main()
{
   int t;
   long  i,j,count;
   long  n,m,z;
   cin>>t;
   while(t--)
   {count=0;
    cin>>z>>m>>n;
    if(m>z)m=z;
    if(n>z)n=z;
    if (m>n)m=n;
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
         if(chk_div(z,i))count++;       
     }

   cout<<count<<"\n";
   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alice is a girl's name.

Comment: `((a/b) * (b) )==a` -> `a % b == 0` (though the compiler might already optimized this for you). also, just a style issue, but prefer using `min` to comparison, your code will be more readable.

Comment: btw OJ usually stops your program after they notive it works longer than time limit. It may work much longer

Comment: FYI eliminating white space doesn't make it run faster.

Comment: @RiaD, " It may work much longer" not may, it is.

Comment: Alice Cooper???

Comment: If x and y are in the range [1,M] and [1,N] respectively, why do you make several test cases? Just take the max you want for M and N, thus eliminating the while-loop. Or do I miss the point?

Comment: run that on test with m = z = n 10^12 on your machine

Comment: Source of question: http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/finding-numbers/

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I doubt MOD is faster than a div+mul. Not sure on it though.

Comment: Ok, just to address the actual question, here's a big hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: Changing cin/cout to scanf/printf can make wonders on speed. Depending on how much time your program spends in I/O, this may be enough to speed it up from 3.008s to 3s.

Comment: @pts: the time his program spends doing I/O is really close to zero.

Comment: @Max reading the question - the given program doesn't solve it. For example - OP completely ignores `n` after reading it.

Comment: What is the point of dividing A by B (a/b), then multiplying the result (a/b) by B. (a/b) * (b). You are doing the same thing. There is no need to divide and multiply because you will get A as your answer. The B`s cancel each other out and you are left with A.

Comment: @Juniar: In integer arithmetic, `a/b*b` does not always equal `a`. (Actually, that is true in any numerical arithmetic, including binary or decimal floating-point and binary or decimal fixed-point.) Testing whether `a/b*b` equals `a` indicates whether `b` exactly divides `a`.

Comment: Wasn't this same exact question asked yesterday?

Comment: @tenfour MOD tends to be pretty similar in performance to just a single DIV (after all, when you do a long division, the remainder is a by-product), so it should be faster than DIV+MUL...

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but still relevant. You said: > Currently the following problem is taking 3.008 [seconds] That is not true. The judges stop the code after 3 seconds. So once you passed the time they kill your job - your job never stopped running. From what I see your code is WAY too slow to take 3 seconds. It probably takes much longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this should get the job done (idea from @zch's answer):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

auto MAX = [] (int A, int B) -> bool { return A > B ? A : B; };
auto MIN = [] (int A, int B) -> bool { return A < B ? A : B; };

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    long long Z, M, N, T, low, high, temp, div;
    int ans;

    for (cin >> T; T--; ) {

        cin >> Z >> M >> N;
        temp = MIN(M, N);
        low = MIN(sqrt(Z), temp);
        high = MAX(M, N);

        for( ans = 0; low > 0 && (Z / low) <= high; --low ) {
            if ( Z % low == 0) {
                ++ans;
                div = Z / low;
                ans += (div != low && div <= temp);
            }
            //cout << temp << " * " << Z / temp << " = " << Z << "\n";
        }
        cout << ans << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Will be adding comments in a bit

**Code with comments**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

auto MAX = [] (int A, int B) -> bool { return A > B ? A : B; };
auto MIN = [] (int A, int B) -> bool { return A < B ? A : B; };

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    long long Z, M, N, T, low, high, temp, div;
    int ans;

    for (cin >> T; T--; ) {

        cin >> Z >> M >> N;
        temp = MIN(M, N);
        low = MIN(sqrt(Z), temp);//Lowest value <--We start iteration from this number
        high = MAX(M, N); //Maximum value

        for( ans = 0; low > 0 && (Z / low) <= high; --low ) {

            //Number of things going on in this for-loop
            //I will start by explaining the condition:
                //We want to keep iterating until either low is below 1
                // or when the expression (Z / low) > high.
                //Notice that as the value of low approaches 0,
                //the expression (Z / low) approaches inf
            if ( Z % low == 0) {

                //If this condition evaluates to true, we know 2 things:
                    /*Z is divisible by this value of low and 
                        low is in the range of MIN(M,N) <--true*/
                    /*Because of our condition, (Z / low) is
                        within the range of MAX(M, N) <--true*/
                ++ans;
                div = Z / low;

                //This second part checks if the opposite is true i.e.
                    /*the value of low is in the range of
                        MAX(M, N) <--true*/
                    /*the value (Z / low) is in the range of
                        MIN(M, N) <--true only in some cases*/
                ans += (div != low && div <= temp);

                //(div != low) is to avoid double counting
                /*An example of this is when Z, M, N have the values:
                    1000000, 1000000, 1000000
                    The value of low at the start is 1000 */
            }
        }
        cout << ans << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A good start. The next step in speed improvement might be to factor Z.

Comment: @Smac89 thanks the code worked... but cant you please explain the   "ans += (div != low && div <= temp);" line in the code

Comment: @MahendraChandwani Here are the [values](http://shrib.com/D8uJnTwi) the code produces when it is run with the values Z = 1000000, M = 1000000, N = 1000000. As you can see from the example, the first output produced is `1000 * 1000`. This is saying that the value of X is 1000 and value of Y is 1000 to produce a product Z. Now if I were to swap the values of X and Y, this is redundant because X is still 1000 and Y is still 1000. So there is no need to count this case more than once because we don't get different values for X and Y

Comment: @MahendraChandwani To maximize the amount of combinations we get, we try to see if some of the higher end values can also fit into the smaller bucket. This why we do `div <= temp`. As the iteration continues div gets larger so doing this, we are able to get as many matches as possible before it gets to large. Note that this simple line of code `ans += (div != low && div <= temp);` keeps us from having to do the iteration twice by making use of the value we have already got.

Answer (score 8):

The main problem with performance here is the fact that your inner loop does about `10^12` iterations. You can reduce it a million times to `sqrt(z) <= 10^6`.

The trick here is to notice that Alice can write `z = x * y` if and only if he can write `z = y * x`. Also, either `x <= sqrt(z)` or `y <= sqrt(z)`. Using these facts you can iterate only up to square root of `z` to count all cases.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you have to resolve the problem in a different way:

find the Prime decomposition:

so `Z = A^a * B^b * ... * P^p` with `A, B, .., P` prime numbers

and so you just have to compute the number of possibilities from `a, b, ... p`.

(So the result is up to `(1 + a) * (1 + b) * ... * (1 + p)` depending of M&N constraints).

Comment: You must also limit the possibilities as specified by M and N.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: According to given constraints, it results that `max(M) == max(N) == Z`.

Comment: The problem statement says that Z, M, and N are read from input as separate integers. M and N may be smaller than or larger than Z. The only constraint is that each of Z, M, and N is at least one and is at most 10**12.

Comment: With this corrected, how does this help to solve the question?

Comment: @zch: For most values of Z, factoring Z greatly reduces the number of cases that must be tested.

Answer (score -1):

- Your if(((a/b) * (b) ) == a) return 1; will always return 1. Why are you dividing A with B (a/b) then multiply the result by B. This is ambiguous because, your answer will be A. when you say, (a/b) * (b). B`s will cancel each other out and you are left with A as your answer. And so basically you are comparing if A == A, which is true.

Comment: `/` for integer types is integer division, discarding remainder. For example `9 / 4 == 2`.

Comment: The point is you are dividing A by B then multiply the result with B. I am not sure if Double is limited or should not be used in this problem for accuracy purpose. I think that is left to the coder.

Comment: `(9 / 4) * 4` will give `2 * 4 != 9`. This check is correct, it would be better written as `a % b == 0`, though.

Comment: If that is the case, I suggest using the mod formula. Even though that might not help with performance issue. But it could be faster. I know for sure that you can do it with one line of instruction with the mod formula, unlike this computation that takes two lines of instructions.

Comment: He could also try ((a/b) * (b) == a) ?  1 : 0; as far as limiting the total number of instructions is concern.